# Convert a German date to ISO date

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I am developing a Node.js application and I have to convert a German string date like `am 13. Dezember 2017` to ISO Date and when I used moment.js library to convert it I got an `invalid date`, any solutions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overlow. In order to help you, you must clarify what are the versions of libraries used and what you tried so far with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): there are a lot of reasons for an invalid date error in momentjs (format, locale, strict mode)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can parse `13. Dezember 2017` using [`moment(String, String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) and then use [`toISOString()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/).

Since your input is neither in ISO 8601 recognized format, neither in RFC 2822 you have to provide format parameter. `DD` stands for day of the month, `MMMM` stands for month's name and `YYYY` stands for 4 digit year.

The third parameter tells moment to parse input using given locale:

> As of version **2.0.0**, a locale key can be passed as the third parameter to `moment()` and `moment.utc()`.

Note that you have to import `de` locale to make it work (using `moment-with-locales.js` or `/locales/de.js` in browser or following [Loading locales in NodeJS](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/loading-into-nodejs/) section for node).

Here a live example:

```js
var m = moment('13. Dezember 2017', 'DD MMMM YYYY', 'de');
console.log( m.toISOString() );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the toISOString method, it return a Date object as a String, using the ISO standard:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toISOString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

https://momentjs.com/docs/

Do you need something like that:

```
moment('13. Dezember 2017', 'DD. MMMM YYYY', 'de').format(moment.ISO_8601);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily format it using:

```
var now = moment(); // pass your date to moment
var formatedNow = moment().toISOString(now);
or
var formatedNow = now.toISOString();
```